# How to get all possible sound combinations for a word

Tags: javascript

I have a list of sounds like so:

```
[ 
  [ 'b', 'v' ],
  [ 'a' ],
  [ 'n', 't' ]
]
```

I need to produce a list of all combinations there sounds can make. The desired output is:

```
[
  'ban',
  'van',
  'bat',
  'vat'
]
```

The best I have been able to come up with so far is a hard-coded solution but the solution must be flexible to accommodate any length of array.

Comment: Must the produced result be always meaningful? If not, then just iterate over the arrays and concatenate the result into a string

Comment: no it need not be meaningful

Comment: thanks for pointing me to cartesian product - exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recursively traverse the combinations and yield the results through a generator:

```
 function* combine([head, ...tail], previous = []) {
   for(const v of head) {
     if(tail.length) {
       yield* combine(tail, [...previous, v]);
     } else yield [...previous, v];
  }
}

// Then just do
console.log(
  [...combine(["bv", "a", "nt"])].map(it => it.join(""))
);
```